# Need help understanding the following MATLAB operations for Gaussian Elimination with Partial Pivoting?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, matlab

[MATLAB code for Guassian Elimination with Partial Pivoting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4D1H.jpg)

I'm having trouble understanding the following segment:

```
for j = 1:n-1

  [m,k] = max (abs(A(j:n,j))

  k = k+j-1

  if k ~= j

    A([k,j],j:n+1) = A([j,k],j:n+1)

  end
```

I'm uncertain about why k is set to be equal to k+j-1. I don't see how that helps to determine if the rows below the pivot element need to be swapped.

Comment: I would be more helpful if you would post the whole code so that other users don't have to go through multiple sources.

Answer (score 1):

The first two lines are the search of the pivot, absolute maximum of the first rows.

$k$ is the pivot.

The two last lines swap $k$-th and $j$-th lines as part of the Gaussian elimination algorithm.